# Problem in numbers significant, absolute error

Tags: approximation, significant-figures

I am learning "Absolute error" in the significant figures. But one exercise I think has written the wrong answer, or I'm confused.

I know that the absolute error has the formula of:

```
| Original value - value approximate |
```

Then, the problem says:

> The best approximation by excess to the `hundredth` of the number
>   `-5,2672` the error that is committed is

```
| 5,2672 - 5,27000 | = 0,0028
```

But the answer is `0.0072`, what am I failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the question suggest, we need an approximation *by excess*.  The approximate value that you used is $-5.27 < -5.2672$.  This leads to a wrong result.  Therefore, we should take $-5.26$ instead.  This will give the desired answer.

$$|\text{original value} - \text{approximate value}| = |(-5.2672) - (-5.26)| = |-0.0072| = 0.0072$$

Comment: Why does it lead to an incorrect result? I thought the approach worked by rounding and that's why I did that.

Comment: How do you know it leads to an incorrect result

Comment: @J.Uchu Since the question asks for an approximation *by excess*, the approximate value should *exceed* the original value (-5.2672).  -5.27 does *not* exceed -5.2672, while -5.26 is the smallest approximation to the hundredth *exceeding* -5.2672.

Comment: Oh, are negative numbers, thanks !!!